# Remove unwanted characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to ask how to remove a special character from a string(extracted from a scrapped page).

```
Â 4:30am
```

I just want to get the time so ive tried so filter it using this:

```
$str = 'Â 4:30am';
$new_string = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $str); 
echo '<pre>'.$new_string.'</pre>';
```

But it doesn't change :|
Is there any solution/approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex is invalid...

```
$str = 'Â 4:30am';
$new_string = preg_replace("~[^a-z0-9:]~i", "", $str); 
echo '<pre>'.$new_string.'</pre>';
```

... and you forgot ":" in the regex, so in your case it will be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Your regex pattern needs to be enclosed by delimiters. Your current pattern is using the `[` and `]` as the delimiters, which most likely isn't what you intended to do.

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $str);
```

http://pl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: It was enclosed in delimiters :) See third example from linked manual and sentence above it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter_var`

```
$str = 'Â 4:30am';
$str = filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
echo $str ;
```

Output

```
4:30am
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$new_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $str);` should fix it.

The first parameter of `preg_replace` is the pattern, which is required to be surrounded by something like `/` or `@`.

In your case, you're using the pattern `[^A-Za-z0-9]` where `[` and `]` are treated as pattern  delimiters. So the actual pattern being matched becomes `^A-Za-z0-9`, which matches nothing in the input.

Answer (score 1):

To get the time:

```
$str = 'Â 4:30am';
$time = preg_match('/(?P<time>\d?\d:\d\d(?:am|pm))/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$new_string = preg_replace("^[A-Za-z0-9]", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Â 4:30am';
$new_string = preg_replace("^\W", "", $str); 
echo '<pre>'.$new_string.'</pre>';
```