# Dynamic find replace part of string

Tags: php

I want to get rid of a part of a PHP variable if it exists. But the difficulty is that this part contains a dynamic element (numbers), which are always different. And the part that remains is not always the same length in words.

> $string = "This is example one 10(+) t/m 16 person";
>
> $string = "This is also an example 12(+) t/m 44 person";
>
> $string = "And this is the final example";

The desired results should be:

> $string = "This is example one";
>
> $string = "This is also an example";
>
> $string = "And this is the final example";

So it needs to filter out the "*(+) t/m * person" and I need to do a lot of this, so a compact and a clear solution is desirable.

Comment: What is your problem? :-)

Comment: It is not possible to determine anything here because the shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 
as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to read the help center, then edit your question, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$words = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $words );
```

this removes you all the numbers than all is left

```
$str = '(+) t/m person ';
    $new= preg_replace("~[^a-z0-9:]~i", "", $str); 
    echo '<pre>'.$new.'</pre>';
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052107/9025311)

Comment: I am glad I helped you

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is removing a string from another string, the most simple way, would be to use str_replace -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

in this way:

str_replace("*(+) t/m * person", "", $string)

This does however rely on you knowing the numbers that go in place of the stars.

A more general solution, which would apply to any problem, could utilise another built in function -

fnmatch - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php